# In an rdlc report, can I programmatically choose one of many possible sub reports in the subreporteventhandler?

Tags: c#, rdlc, report

I have a main report, with a space for a sub report. Depending on one of the main report parameters, I want to load one of many different possible sub reports. I got kind of excited when I saw a report path parameter in the subreportprocessingeventargs, but that turned out to be READ ONLY!

So, can someone please tell me it's possible to change the report definition programmatically? I've got my heart set on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not choose between sub-reports. The but you can add all the sub-reports one after another the using the parameter form the main report set Hidden "False" only to one for the sub-reports. This way you will have all sub-reports in the report but only one will be shown.

Comment: will the hidden reports show as a big blob of white space, or do hidden reports take up no space?

Comment: Hi, it depends what is the way out of the report. Let's say if the report has Table control and in one of the rows of this Table control is placed the sub-report. The when you say Hidden "True" to this row i will not show as white space in the report. So it depends on layout of the report